# Slick: Put model case classes in separate object using code generator

Tags: scala, code-generation, slick-2.0

I am using the slick code generator, I have everything in a trait, but I would like to separate the case classes representing my actual model from all the slick query / table classes.

That would look like

```
object Models {
  case class Foo(bar: String)
}

trait SlickTables {
  import Models.Foo
  class Foos(tag: Tag) extends Table[Foo](tag, "foo") {
    ...
  }
}
```

Is there any way to do this by tweaking the code generator ?

Comment: I usually split them manually, I couldn't find a way to do it form the code generator and I don't think there's a way to do it that doesn't involve some coding.

Comment: Ok, the main advantage of the code generator is not to have to do this manually but I think you're right it would require to fork slick and modify the code generator logic. I might try to do this, but for now I think I will leave everything as it is and make it an object instead of a trait.

Comment: Really need this feature! So annoying to import table._ every where in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Just figure a way out.

https://gist.github.com/noru/fd32b03947290176aa36

Around line 80